# SQL order by with default options appearing above

Tags: mysql, sql

If I wanted to display a list of names in ascending order, except for a few defaults, how could I achieve this with an SQL order by clause.

eg result:

```
place
-------
United States
United Kingdom
Bahrain
Australia
Fiji 
Indonesia
Japan
Korea
....
```

Where United States, United Kingdom and Bahrain are some defaults we want to come before the regular ascending order list from the database - all of these (including the defaults are fetched form the database and not hardcoded). The defaults should be in a defined order as above (not asc, or desc)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. I used conditional `ORDER BY` using `CASE` statement in my query:

```
SELECT 
      place 
FROM #yourtable 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN place='United States' THEN '1'
      WHEN place='United Kingdom' THEN '2'
      WHEN place='Bahrain' THEN '3'
      ELSE place
 END)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I was looking into case statements but couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way to do this would be to add a column to the table `default_seq int`. Set it to `0` for non-default columns, and to a positive value for the default ones, with the highest number being the one to come first.

Then the query becomes:

```
select place
from your_table
order by default_seq desc, place asc
```

This has the advantage that defaults may be changed without changing any code.

Answer (score 0):

To create your desired result you could use `UNION` as below. The `UNION` operator combines the result from two or more select statements:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM <table> 
  WHERE place IN ( 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Bahrain' ) 
  ORDER BY place DESC 
) A 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM <table> 
  WHERE place NOT IN ( 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Bahrain' )
  ORDER BY place ASC 
) B;
```

Comment: Thanks, went with the other option.

Comment: @Martin - That happends =) In fact I believe the other answer should be faster. Still my solution works anyway.